# What is the most usual verb in this case of interpretation of the text on crimes? Alternatives A or B?

Tags: verbs

Read the following extracts were taken from a article from St. Louis Today.

> The lady in accounting at Schunuck's headquarters in Maryland Heights quictly pocketed small sums that, over three years, added up to more than $111,000, authorities said. A felony theft charge was field earlier this month. While the alleged theft was brazen—most bank robbers could only hope for such a haul—the case was merely the latest in a series of embezzlements across the St. Louis Region. As prosecutors prepared to file charges in the Schunucks case, St. Louis County government officials were untangling how a manager in the health department allegedly pilfered $3.4 million in public funds over six years. That same day, a former town supervisor in tiny Moro in Madison County pleaded guilty to writing small checks to himself for "office expenses" that totaled more than $750,000 over a decade. Also, a former Edwardsville police chief was sentenced for stealing $138,000 Worth of vehicle impound fees over a three-year-span. Other high-profile cases have emerged in the last month, too, such as two St. Louis parks workers admitting last month they used sham invoices to steal more than $460,000 over eight years.

This sentence:

> The former town supervisor in tiny México in Madison County pleaded guilty to writing small checks to himself for "office expenses" that totalled more than $750,000 over a decade.

Does it mean that: A) He acknowledged doing that, or B)He confessed he had a partner in crime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely A. There's nothing in that sentence that indicates an accomplice or any other actor at all. To 'plead guilty' is to make a formal acknowledgement of guilt in a court of law.

In other words, the judge says, "Did you do this?"

To which he replies, "I did."